# Add new update in farm

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, workflow-manager

I have SharePoint farm with workflow manager!

We are planning to update our farm with the latest update

Will I need to rerun the register cmdle, after applying the update?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need to rerun, the Register-SPWorkflowService cmdlet should only be run once for the entire SharePoint farm. Once a SharePoint farm is associated with Workflow Manager the cmdlet does not need to be run again unless you are restoring SharePoint from a backup.